# How can I improve the speed of a SQL query searching for a collection of strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, text-search

I have a table called `T_TICKET` with a column `CallId varchar(30)`.

Here is an example of my data:

```
CallId               | RelatedData
===========================================
MXZ_SQzfGMCPzUA      | 0000
MXyQq6wQ7gVhzUA      | 0001
MXwZN_d5krgjzUA      | 0002
MXw1YXo7JOeRzUA      | 0000
...
```

I am attempting to find records that match a collection of `CallId`'s. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T_TICKET WHERE CALLID IN(N'MXZInrBl1DCnzUA', N'MXZ0TWkUhHprzUA', N'MXZ_SQzfGMCPzUA', ... ,N'MXyQq6wQ7gVhzUA')
```

And I have anywhere from 200 - 300 `CallId`'s that I am looking up at a time using this query. The query takes around 35 seconds to run. **Is there anything I can do to either the table structure, the column type, the index, or the query itself to improve the performance of this query?**

There are around 300,000 rows in `T_INDEX` currently. `CallId` is not unique. And `RelatedData` is not unique. I also have an index (non-clustered) on `CallId`.

I know the basics of SQL, but I'm not a pro. Some things I've thought of doing are:

1. Change the type of `CallId` from `varchar` to `char`.
2. Shorten the length of `CallId` (it's length is 30, but in reality, right now, I am using only 15 bytes).

I have not tried any of these yet because it requires changes to live production data. And, I am not sure they would make a significant improvement.

Would either of these options make a significant improvement? Or, are there other things I could do to make this perform faster?

Comment: but you did not use the `index`... try this  `SELECT * FROM T_TICKET with (index=T_INDEX) WHERE ...` as see if that improves.. for a `varchar` type you don't need the `N'`

Comment: Changing the type to a CHAR(15) also comes to mind. Are you unable to restore a backup of the production's T_TICKET table to your local machine?

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure that the types are the same -- either `VARCHAR()` or `NVARCHAR()`.  Then, add an index:

```
create index idx_t_ticket_callid on t_ticket(callid);
```

If the types are compatible, SQL Server should make use of the index.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I already have an index for `CallId` on the table. I'm hoping to improve it further.

Comment: @MattSpinks Now is the time to stop making everyone guess - including yourself. Post **complete** DDL of the table involved. You first said "300,000 row in T_Index" - what is T_Index? And look at the execution plan - posting it using [brentozar](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) will help.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is what we called [heap (a table without clustered index)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017). This kind of tables only good for data loading and/or as staging table. I would recommend you to convert your table to have a clustered key. A good clustering key should be unique, static, narrow, non-nullable, and ever-increasing (eg. `int`/`bigint` identity datatype).

Another downside of heap is when you have lots of `UPDATE`/`DELETE` on your table, it will slow down your `SELECT` because of forwarded records. Quoting from Paul Randal about forwarded records:

> If a forwarding record occurs in a heap, when the record locator points to that location, the Storage Engine gets there and says Oh, the record isn't really here – it's over there! And then it has to do another (potentially physical) I/O to get to the page with the forwarded record on. This can result in a heap being less efficient that an equivalent clustered index.

Lastly, make sure you define all your columns on your `SELECT`. Avoid the `SELECT *`. I'm guessing you are experiencing a `table scan` when you execute the query. What you can do is `INCLUDE` all columns list on your `SELECT` on your index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_T_TICKET_CallId_INCLUDE] ON [T_TICKET] ([CallId]) INCLUDE ([RelatedData]) WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON)
```

Comment: Great answer just some nitpicks: Including the columns in the index may not substantially decrease the query time and be offset by the larger index size cost. Also `CallId` should be the prime candidate to be considered for the primary key assuming it is unique (even if the potential non-increasing nature makes not ideal).

Comment: Great ideas, but unfortunately I do not have control over the values in `CallId`. I might be able to change the type of the `CallId` column, but the values are coming from an external source. Also, as specified in the question, `CallId` is not unique.

Comment: @MattSpinks try adding the `INCLUDE` on your nonclustered index.. this will speed things up.. expected an index seek instead of table scan. And I dont think you need to change the data type of `CallId`.

Comment: @EliAlgranti i strongly disagree. `INCLUDE` when done right, it can improve query speed/time performance. It significantly reduces the number of IO when querying the data, it reduces the read time from cache as well because it read less pages. `CallId` is not a good choice for clustered index! because it will be in every nonclustered index you have. Especially `string` datatypes.

Comment: @dco I accept include speeds up queries, but they have downsides. You are basically tailoring your index to the specific query that needs the extra columns, you are also decreasing the finite memory cache available to other queries. Sometimes it is not worth it, sometimes it is.

Comment: @dco As to CallId being considered as a primary key for the clustered index. It looks as the natural/business key for that data. I.e. that is the identifier the business uses for that data. If that is the case it'll end up in most indexes or queries you create anyway because that is how it is identified in the system. The downside is the tree restructuring on insertion because it is not increasing, but again this is not a rule just a consideration.

Comment: @EliAlgranti i appreciate your thoughts on this. maybe you are right academically but not in a real-world workloads. **A clustered index on a string data type will not scale**. SQL Server needs to order every time you insert/update the string and that's very expensive. You will experience fragmentation and bad page split. An alternative would be primary unique nonclustered index key.

Comment: @dco noted on the nonclustered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is in fact a way to significantly optimize my query without changing any data types.

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM T_TICKET 
WHERE CALLID IN(N'MXZInrBl1DCnzUA', N'MXZ0TWkUhHprzUA', N'MXZ_SQzfGMCPzUA', ... ,N'MXyQq6wQ7gVhzUA')
```

is using `NVARCHAR` types as the input params `(N'MXZInrBl1DCnzUA', N'MXZ0TWkUhHprzUA'...)`. As I specified in my question, `CallId` is `VARCHAR`. Sql Server was converting `CallId` in every row of the table to an `NVARCHAR` type to do the comparison, which was taking a long time (even though I have an index on `CallId`).

I was able to optimize it by simply NOT changing the parameter types to `NVARCHAR`:

```
SELECT * FROM T_TICKET 
WHERE CALLID IN('MXZInrBl1DCnzUA', 'MXZ0TWkUhHprzUA', 'MXZ_SQzfGMCPzUA', ... ,'MXyQq6wQ7gVhzUA')
```

Now, instead of taking over 30 seconds to run, it only takes around .03 seconds. Thanks for all the input.

Comment: nice! that is called implicit conversion. Make sure you add your table definition next time on your question :)